# How much does creating and closing a thread cost in ms?

Tags: multithreading, c++11

Generally how much does a `std::thread t (some function )` and `t.join ()` cost cpu in ms ? Does it even weigh on cpu opening and closing a thread ?

Comment: Have you tried setting up a program to measure it?

Comment: [42 ms](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=the%20answer%20to%20life%20the%20universe%20and%20everything)

Comment: No i didn't  actually. The thing is i don't  an exact  measured response. I needed to know if it does weigh at all

Comment: This is OS specific, among other things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thread creation and destruction does cost something, of course. Not as much as process creation/destruction because threads share most of the resources between them (address space being the most important), but still it does cost.

This is the reason that if you have M tasks and N cores where M >> N (significantly larger) instead of creating a thread for each task, it is sometimes faster if you create a pool of ~N threads (called workers). You have the added synchronization costs, but you gain by not creating/destroying so many threads.

Join is another discussion, as join is not the same thing as closing a thread. Join is waiting for the thread to finish.